# Sendmail sending @samedomain emails to /var/mail/root

Tags: debian, sendmail

I found out a lot of people with the same problem but anybody actually solved it aparently

The thing is that i can send emails to anyone@anywhere but when i send to @mydomain it is sending to /var/mail/root

and in /etc/mail/local-host-names there is just "localhost" written, which i commented and still the same problem

Comment: Details please.  SMTP server, config files...

Comment: I use google apps to receive emails, sendmail is using it's default configurations, im on a debian

Comment: alright i solved using the first solution here: http://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail but it's not exactly what i want, i want to disable it for all future domains i put on this server

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [blog post](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2011/03/14/mail-hosted-at-google-web-server-elsewhere/) that covers similar problems. Maybe it can be of help to you.