# Using Gmail apps. New VPS. All mail working except incoming mail to @domain.com emails sent from server

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, mx-record, gmail

So I just noticed this issue, and it's rather urgent we find a solution, it's literally been ongoing unnoticed several days, as any communication being sent to us from our email forms and offer forms on the site are essentially going into a black hole.

We just did a change from Shared to a VPS. Have been using Google Apps Gmail all along.

Not sure if this is a misconfigured DNS or what but it's odd that every possible way of sending and receiving mail works, except when the server sends mail to emails with the @domain.com's email address.

Does anyone perhaps know what can cause this issue? Or a way to debug it? It'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First check the server's logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new VPS might have an email service installed & configured in such a way that it think it is authoritative for @domain.com - so it's not relaying any emails toward your Google Apps account.

An easy way to confirm would be to check /var/log/maillog (or /var/log/mail).

The exact Plesk (Parallel) knowledge base article to fix your problem is here: http://kb.parallels.com/en/116927. Here's a repost of the interesting extract:

> ```
> Disable mail service for the domain.tld subscription:
> Go to Subscriptions > domain.tld > Mail > Change Settings.
> Uncheck Activate mail service on domain and click OK.
>
> You may also disable mail service on the subscription using the command-line utility mail:
> /usr/local/psa/bin/mail --off domain.tld
> ```

Comment: Thanks Cloud! This did the trick :) Whew.............. :D

Comment: Now it's an entirely different issue figuring out where all that other mail went off to.. fun fun

Comment: The other mail should have been bounced back to sender because recipient didn't exist - which mean yourself, which should mean postmaster, which should mean root on the box). I would suggest looking into /var/mail/root (or /var/spool/mail/root) file.

Answer (score 0):

If your server hostname is in the same domain, your email will try to go to local users. You have to configure mail sender correctly.

Example: mailserver.example.com

- Email sent from this server to XXX@example.com will go to local user mailbox.

You can refere to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail) post on how disable local delivery